# NullPointerException when injecting Spring service bean to JSF ManagedBean

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2, dependency-injection

Tomcat 7, JSF 2, Spring 3, Java 6

Error: NullPointerException on userService.checkUser(getLogin()) (userService is null) in UserBean.java when accessing jsf page.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
           version="2.5">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
              version="2.0">
    <application>
       <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>i18n</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>ru</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Services Beans -->
    <bean id="userService" class="service.UserServiceImpl">
        <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- DAOs -->
    <bean id="userDao" class="dao.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

UsersBean.java

```
package beans;

import service.UserService;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;

@ManagedBean(name="usersBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UsersBean implements Serializable{
    private String login;
    private String password;
    @ManagedProperty(name = "userService", value = "#{userService}")
    private UserService userService;

    ...Getters, setters for every field...

    public void checkRegistred(){
        userService.checkUser(getLogin());
    }
}
```

xhtml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <title>Simple JSF Facelets page</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="layout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:link value="First page" outcome="index.xhtml"></h:link>
            <br/>
            <h:link value="Third page" outcome="third.xhtml"></h:link>
            <br/>
            Hello #{usersBean.login} with pass #{usersBean.password}
            <br/>
            You are #{usersBean.checkRegistred()}
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8925170/980472) and its answer. In your case, as you are using XML configuration, for working with @autowired annotation, also, you need to modify your userServide declaratin as follow:

```
<bean id="userService" class="service.UserServiceImpl" autowire-candidate="true">
    <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"/>
</bean>
```

With the `autowire-candidate` attribute set to true, `userService` will be available for autowired.

**Updated:**

```
package beans;

import ...

@SessionScoped
public class UsersBean implements Serializable {

    private String login;

    private String password;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    ...Getters, setters for every field...

    public void checkRegistred(){
        userService.checkUser(getLogin());
    }

}
```

Also, in your XML it should found:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="beans.*" />
<context:annotation-config />
```

Comment: Now i have another error: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @23,114 value="#{usersBean.login}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'usersBean' resolved to null
It is on line: <h:inputText id="name" value="#{usersBean.login}" required="true" requiredMessage="Name, please"></h:inputText>

Comment: Did you defined your `UsersBean` as I described above? It look error is the same as previously: usersBean is null.

Comment: It was because faces-config.xml has not been under WEB-INF directory. Stupid mistake. Thanks for help.