# @Scope("request") not working

Tags: spring, jsf-2, scope, request

I am experimenting with JSF and Primefaces ( JSF 2.0.2 ,PrimeFaces 3.0.5, Spring 3.0.0). It seems I am unable to access managed bean from a xhtml page such as

```
<h:inputText  id="lastName" value="#{personalBean.personal_Basic.firstName}"  label="Last Name"  required="true" />
```

The request starts from a command link's invocation to bean method, service and returns the page. I could see in servers console Bean, service methods are executed. I am not seeing anything when I try to use beans attributes as above. However I am able to access session scoped bean used for session management of the user.

Sorry if this question is too naive. Any input to resolve the problem is greatly appreciated.

Below are my code snips. This is how I call the bean:

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandLink id="ajax" actionListener="#{personalBean.getPersonalInfo}" style="margin-left:5px;">  
        <h:outputText value="Personal Info" />  <br/>
    </p:commandLink>  
</h:form>
```

Below is the request scoped managed bean.

```
package com.test.model;
@ManagedBean
@Scope("request")
public class PersonalBean  implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 199L;
private Personal_Basic personal_Basic;
private IPersonalService personalService;

@Inject
public PersonalBean(final IPersonalService personalService) {
    this.personalService = personalService;
}
public String getPersonalInfo() {
    System.out.println("\n\nPersonalBean#getPersonalInfo called...**");
    User user = null;
    Personal_Basic personal_Basic = personalService.getPersonalBasic();
    this.setPersonal_Basic(personal_Basic);
    System.out.println("personal_Basic data:"+personal_Basic);
    System.out.println("PersonalBean#getPersonalInfo ended...");
    return "/page/personal.html";
}
// Getters/setters for class members followed
}
```

PersonalService implementation is annotated with @Service.

Below is the excerpt from spring configuration xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config/> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>
...................
...................
</beans>
```

Below is the excerpt from faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
              version="2.0">
  <application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>Messages</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
        </locale-config>
  </application>
...........................
</faces-config>
```

Comment: No error messages in server (Tomcat 6.0) console, logs. :(

Comment: The `@Scope` has **nothing** to do with JSF. It's part of Spring. So to get attention from the right guys who can answer your question, it's important to tag the question appropriately. I've added the missing `[spring]` tag to your question.

Comment: @BalusC Sorry. I missed to do that. I wanted to mention @ RequestScoped, but mentioned the old code.

Comment: JSF doesn't support the construct `@Inject public PersonalBean(final IPersonalService personalService)`. So you really have to go in the Spring direction, or to stop using it to manage the beans.

Comment: I am not sure, but I can see personalService is properly created and injected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>` element scans and registers all beans annotated with @Component, @Repository, @Service, or @Controller by default.

Spring also offers support for `javax.annotation.ManagedBean` (not `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`) and JSR-330 standard annotations and these are also scanned by Spring but you need to have the following dependency added to your project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

You can see all the equivalent annotations for Spring annotations [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-standard-annotations), as you can see the equivalent of @Component is @Named and for the scope use Springs @Scope annotation instead of `javax.inject.scope` as mentioned.
So if you want **Spring to manage** all the beans in your application you can use either `@Component`, `@Named` and `javax.annotation.ManagedBean` annotation and inject them using @Autowired or @Inject.

And to your question why beans annotated with `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean` seem to be initialized but do not work is because as mentioned by @BalusC, @Inject is not supported in JSF you have to use @ManagedProperty annotation.

A little background on how it all works with Spring and JSF:

Actually there are two IOC containers in your application now with JSF and Spring, when the application starts up.
First the org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver configured in your faces-config.xml delegates to the Spring root WebApplicationContext first resolving name references to Spring-defined beans, then to the default resolver of the underlying JSF implementation.

Now when the JSF bean is first looked up it is constructed and then the managed property is set via the setter method so you can inject a Spring bean using the @ManagedProperty annotation like this:

```
package com.test.model;
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class PersonalBean  implements Serializable {
@ManagedProperty(value="#{personalService}")
private IPersonalService personalService;
public IPersonalService getPersonalService() {
    return personalService;
}

public void setPersonalService(IPersonalService personalService) {
    this.personalService= personalService;
}
```

or you can also manually get the Spring bean using

`org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils` like this:

```
private Object getSpringBean(String name){
        WebApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(
                (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext());
        return ctx.getBean(name);
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Personal_Basic personal_Basic = ((IPersonalService) getSpringBean("personalService")).getPersonalBasic();
```

But instead of using two containers in your applications you can just use the Spring container to manage all your beans by annotating JSF beans with @Component and there are no implications as such that I am aware of and should be perfectly alright to use Spring annotations.

See also:

- [Difference between <context:annotation-config> vs <context:component-scan>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414794/difference-between-contextannotation-config-vs-contextcomponent-scan)
- [JSR-330 support for component detection is inconsistent](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6465)
- [Spring Documentation - JSF Integration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html)
- [Using Spring to Manage JSF beans](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2007/09/10/using-spring-to-manage-jsf-beans/)

Comment: Perfect! I removed @ManagedBean and annotation-config from spring xml. component-scan works like a charm. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I did. However I still wonder why @ManagedBean doesnt work? I guess we can set request scope to Component. But does it have any implications ?

Comment: @bkrish, see the updated answer for a more detailed explanation!

Comment: Are we supposed to see ManagedBean's name in ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames() ? i.e "PersonalService". If yes, it doesnt. And, WebApplicationContext doesnt return Bean and throws exception "No such bean". However PersonalService is properly instantiated and injected at ManagedBean's setter method.

Comment: Did you try "personalService"? i.e lowercase p or do you have @Qalifier on your Spring bean?

Comment: Sorry. Environment Issue. Thanks for your help !  :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix @ManagedBean with spring scopes, You have to choose between @ManagedBean and @RequestScope or @Componenet and @Scope("session")