# Using Hibernate package to access database from another package

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jsf

I have divided my project into 2 packages. I'm using Maven.

**package 1**
It's a hibernate package, means it contains POJO classes, DAO classes and interfaces, BO classes and interfaces, and hibernate configurations. It generates a JAR file.

**package 2**
It's a JSF package, containing only web pages and managed beans, I'm also using ICEfaces.

My goal is to include the JAR file of the first package in the build path of the 2nd package, and use the methods of the BO classes to access the database from the web pages.

First I will list all configurations files of the first package:

**AppContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="bankBankBO" 
         class="bdl.cdr.core.bo.impl.BankBankBOImpl" >
        <property name="bankBankDAO" ref="bankBankDAO" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="bankBankDAO" 
         class="bdl.cdr.core.dao.impl.BankBankDAOImpl" >
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**DataSource.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>jdbc.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**HibernateSessionFactory.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
         <prop key="current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext</prop>
       </props>
    </property>

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
        <value>bdl.cdr.core.pojo.BankBank</value>
    </list>
    </property>

    </bean>
</beans>
```

**jdbc.properties**

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db2inst1
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=root
```

**BeanLocations.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- Database Configuration -->
    <import resource="DataSource.xml"/>
    <import resource="HibernateSessionFactory.xml"/>
    <import resource="AppContext.xml"/>

</beans>
```

I'm using JUnit to test, and everything is working fine.

Now what I did is to take the JAR file built by Maven and I included it in the Build Path of the 2nd Package.

And this is what I tried to do:

I created a Service Factory (or BO Factory) class:

```
public class ServiceFactory {

    public static BankBankBO bankBankService;

    public static BankBankBO getBankBankService() {
        return bankBankService;
    }
}
```

In `faces-config.xml` I added the following:

```
<managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>serviceFactory</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>bdl.cdr.portlet.utils.ServiceFactory</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>bankBankService</property-name>
            <property-class>bdl.cdr.core.bo.BankBankBO</property-class>
            <value>#{bankBankBO}</value>
        </managed-property>
    </managed-bean>
```

In another bean linked to a web page, I created a click event on a button:

```
public void print(ActionEvent ae) {
        ServiceFactory.getBankBankService().findAll();
    }
```

The `findAll` method, should return the list of all Banks from the database, the return type is the POJO class from the hibernate package, called `BankBank`.

After clicking the button, I receive the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Received 'java.lang.NullPointerException' when invoking action listener '#{jasperBean.print}' for component '_t38'
Jul 12, 2014 11:42:29 PM javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener processAction
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at bdl.cdr.portlet.managedbeans.main.interfacemodule.JasperBean.print(JasperBean.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:148)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:775)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Jul 12, 2014 11:42:29 PM org.icefaces.impl.application.ExtendedExceptionHandler handle
WARNING: queued exception
javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: /index.xhtml @23,74 actionListener="#{jasperBean.print}": java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:182)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:775)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at bdl.cdr.portlet.managedbeans.main.interfacemodule.JasperBean.print(JasperBean.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:148)
    ... 21 more

Jul 12, 2014 11:42:29 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl log
SEVERE: JSF1073: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException caught during processing of INVOKE_APPLICATION 5 : UIComponent-ClientId=j_idt37:_t38, Message=/index.xhtml @23,74 actionListener="#{jasperBean.print}": java.lang.NullPointerException
Jul 12, 2014 11:42:29 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl log
SEVERE: /index.xhtml @23,74 actionListener="#{jasperBean.print}": java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: /index.xhtml @23,74 actionListener="#{jasperBean.print}": java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:182)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:775)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at bdl.cdr.portlet.managedbeans.main.interfacemodule.JasperBean.print(JasperBean.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:148)
    ... 21 more
```

I can provide the contents of all other classes and files, `web.xml` , `faces-config.xml` and whatever you need.

Thanks.

Comment: ServiceFactory.getBankBankService() is returning null, because bankBankService isn't initialised...

Comment: @MGorgon yes I realized this some minutes ago, how should I initialize it? isn't mentioning it in `faces-config.xml` enough?

Comment: @AliBassam bankBankBO is Spring Bean, while ServiceFactory is JSF Managed Bean, so injection of bankBankService isn't working. Read about JSF-Spring integration, for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925170/jsf-2-inject-spring-bean-service-with-managedproperty-and-no-xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bankBankBO is Spring Bean, while ServiceFactory is JSF Managed Bean, so injection of bankBankService isn't working.

You must add this:

```
<application>
    <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
    <variable-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver</variable-resolver>
</application>
```

to your faces-config.xml, in order to enable spring beans to jsf beans injection.